# Query - can't select childs data-attribute (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT: IT WAS A TYPO, I'VE OVERSEEN. Please ignore this question**
I want to select the data-key attribute from the span inside a li-element, when the checkbox is checked.

```
<li class="result-set-list-item">
    <input class="result-select-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
    <span class="list-item-content" data-key="foobar">Das Foobar</span>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#result-list-ul li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.result-select-checkbox').attr('checked') == 'checked') {
     console.log($(this).children("span").first().data['key']); }
    ...
```

Even when `$(this).children("span")`  returns an valid array including the span, I cannot access the data-attribute using `(this).children("span").first().data['key']`

How should I access the span in this case? I got lots of elements and I don't want to implement an id for each span.

Comment: `$(this).children("span").first().data('key');`

Comment: oh my god I've overseen the  square brackets ...

Comment: sorry guys I will delete this question, since I don't think a typo should be discussed. But Its pretty funny to see, this question got 4 answers until now

Comment: Goot, stop freaking out. We all make mistakes and typos. Its ok, who knows, somebody might somehow benefit from this post in the future

Answer (score 1):

Call it like function

```
$(this).children("span").first().data('key');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use .is() and :checked to see whether the checkbox is checked
2. .data() is a function so you need to invoke the function and pass teh data key as an argument to it

So

```
$('#result-list-ul li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.result-select-checkbox').is(':checked')) {//use :checked to see if checked
        console.log($(this).children("span").first().data('key'));//use () to call the data function
    }
```

A shortened version is

```
$('#result-list-ul li:has(.result-select-checkbox:checked)').each(function () {
    //will execute only for li's with checked items
    console.log($(this).children("span").first().data('key')); //use () to call the data function
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) is a method in jQuery and not an `object/array`. Use it by passing the key in like

```
console.log($(this).children("span").first().data('key'));
```

```js
$('li').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).children("span").first().data('key'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="result-set-list-item">
  <input class="result-select-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
  <span class="list-item-content" data-key="foobar">Das Foobar</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the checked boxes

```
var cb = $('.result-select-checkbox:checked', this)
```

To get the value of the data attribute

```
$(cb).data('key')
```